# How to encode the RAW into its BASE64 form thru the UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE function in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, base64, blob

Is there a way to convert a BLOB to RAW? I looked at UTL_RAW package in Oracle but could not find a way to convert BLOB to RAW. My goal is after the conversion, I want to encode the RAW into its BASE64 form thru the UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE function. This function only takes RAW.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle BLOB to base64 CLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155620/oracle-blob-to-base64-clob)