# Oracle apex how to display in report images from collection

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1

I'm trying to display an image from a collection.

The current methods (apex_util.get_blob_file_src / dbms_lob.getlength) don't seem to work, since this is a collection and not a Table.
I'm able to create a download link of the image/file but not display it.
Any ideas on how to display images from collection in a report?

The report query looks like that (without the section to display image)

```
select
    seq_id as "Seq id",

    n001 as "Id",

    '<a href="' || apex_page.get_url(p_page => 3003, 
                                 p_clear_cache => 3003,
                                 p_items => 'P3003_SEQ', 
                                 p_values => seq_id)
        ||'">' || c002 || '</a>'
    as "Download document"

from APEX_COLLECTIONS
where collection_name = 'COLLECTION_DOCS';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could transform the image to base64 with a function and use the output in the img src attribute.

[Here is some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155620/oracle-blob-to-base64-clob) to transform the blob to a base64 encoded clob.

Afterwards you can use that clob in an HTML img tag:

```html
<img alt="" src="data:'|| img_mime_type || ';base64, '|| base64_img || '">
```

You need to set the mime type based on your image format. E. g. for png use "image/png".

Comment: Thanks! your solution is working, but unfortunately only for small images. I tried making some changes in the code mentioned in your link (I used the function since I cannot use procedure). My best-case scenario is when I use this code:
return UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(image_blob, 22500, 1))) --> where image_blob is the BLOB column.
Using for loop, as mentioned in the link and other places, cause "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small". Do you know how can I solve it?

Comment: BTW, if relevant, the VARCHAR2 is max 4000 since the DB definition is not set to "Extended"